# Having trouble proving this integral is infinite

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am working on an assignment and I have to prove that

$$\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \notin L_1\mathbb{R}^2)$$

to justify why Fubini's Theorem does not apply. I figured that the best way to do this is to prove that

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{|x^2-y^2|}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dxdy = \infty$$

However I'm not sure how to go about doing this...any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens with the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

What you can note is that if you choose some wedge of plane, like the points for which $-\frac{1}2x<y<\frac{1}2x$, you can note that, if we let $r$ be $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, i.e. the distance from the origin to the point $(x,y)$, then the numerator in this wedge is always at least $cr^2$ for some $c$ and the denominator is exactly $r^4$. So, we could set up an integral which is strictly less than the given integral, in polar coordinates, where $\alpha$ is the appropriate bound for the angle:

$$\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{cr^2}{r^4}r \,dr\, d\theta$$
$$\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}\int_{0}^{1}c\frac{1}r \, dr\, d\theta$$

but the inner integral diverges.